# How to query by object attributes from IMap<String,Set<MyObject>>?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Hazelcast [docs](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Query/Querying_in_Collections_and_Arrays/index.html) explain how to do this when we have `IMap<String,Object>`, but nothing about the case when map value is a collection.

I see two options:

- wrap the `Set<Object>` into a wrapper type, thus enabling returning the `Set`, which would then need to be locally filtered;
- implement [ValueExtractor](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Query/Custom_Attributes/index.html), but not completely sure about that, as haven't used it so far.

**Edit**: implementation ended up being similar to what mikhail-baksheev suggested. Note the `CollectionExtractor` uses ifblock to decide which field from `MyObject` should be collected. Is there any prettier (but still efficient) solution for this?

```
public class CollectionExtractor extends ValueExtractor<Set<MyObject>, String> {

    @Override
    public void extract(
            final Set<MyObject> target,
            final String argument,
            final ValueCollector collector ) {

        if ( argument.equals( "field_1" ) ) {
            for ( final MyObject o : target ) {
                collector.addObject( o.getField_1() );
            }
        } else if ( argument.equals( "field_2" ) ) {
            for ( final MyObject o : target ) {
                collector.addObject( o.getField_2() );
            }
        }
    }
}

@Getter
public class MyObject implements Serializable {

    private String field_1;
    private String field_2;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For instance, you want to query some objects  which is defined as set of parameters `Set<Parameter>`:

```
public class Parameter {
    private String name;
    private Object value;

    public Parameter( String name, Object value ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

At first, implement ValueExtarcator for `Parameters`:

```
public class ParameterExtractor extends ValueExtractor<Set<Parameter>, String> {
   @Override
   public void extract( Set<Parameter> parameters, String parameterName, ValueCollector collector ) {
      for ( Parameter p : parameters ) {
          if ( parameterName.equals( p.getName() ) ) {
              collector.addObject( p.getValue() );
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Next, add the ValueExtractor to the map config for custom attribute `parameter`:

```
Config config = new Config( "my-instance" );
MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig( "map" );
mapConfig.addMapAttributeConfig( new MapAttributeConfig( "parameter", ParameterExtractor.class.getName() ) );
config.addMapConfig( mapConfig );
```

Add some data into the map:

```
HazelcastInstance hzInstance = Hazelcast.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance( config );
IMap<String, Set<Parameter>> objectsMap = hzInstance.getMap( "map" );
objectsMap.put( "user1", ImmutableSet.of(
                new Parameter( "type", "user" ),
                new Parameter( "firstName", "Joe" ) ) );
```

Now you can query data with specified Property by using square brackets:

```
objectsMap.values( Predicates.and( Predicates.equal( "parameter[type]", "user" ), Predicates.equal( "parameter[firstName]", "Joe" ) ) );
```

Value in square brackets is a [custom argument](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Query/Custom_Attributes/Extraction_Arguments.html), this value will be passed to `extract` method of value extractor as the second argument and can be used to find needed property.

**Edit**: If you have special type for objects in set with defined fields, e.g. `MyObject` class from your example, you can implement ValueExtractor for each field of `MyObject` instead of using custom attributes to find needed field:

```
public class Field_1Extractor extends ValueExtractor<Set<MyObject>, String> {
    @Override
    public void extract(
            final Set<MyObject> target,
            final String argument,
            final ValueCollector collector ) {

            for ( final MyObject o : target ) {
                collector.addObject( o.getField_1() );
            }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Also you can use ValueExtractor to find entries which contains specifc element in value collection. For example, extractor for "any" predicate: `list[any] == some value`:

```
public class ListValueExtractor extends ValueExtractor<List<String>, String> implements Serializable {

    @Override
    public void extract( List<String> listValues, String argument, ValueCollector collector ) {
        if ( "any".equals( argument ) ) {
            for ( String v : listValues ) {
                collector.addObject( v );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Config cfg = new Config();
        MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig( "things" );
        mapConfig.addMapAttributeConfig( new MapAttributeConfig( "list", ListValueExtractor.class.getName() ) );//register extractor for 'list'
        cfg.addMapConfig( mapConfig );
        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance( cfg );
        IMap<String, List<String>> mapThings = instance.getMap( "things" );

        mapThings.put( "Joe", new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add( "apple" );
            add( "box" );
            add( "laptop" );
        }} );

        mapThings.put( "Denis", new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add( "apple" );
            add( "pencil" );
            add( "jacket" );
        }} );
        EntryObject e = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
        Predicate withApple = Predicates.equal( "list[any]", "apple" );
        Predicate withLaptop = Predicates.equal( "list[any]", "laptop" );

        List<String> usersWithApple = mapThings.entrySet( withApple ).stream().map( Map.Entry::getKey ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
        List<String> usersWithLaptop = mapThings.entrySet( withLaptop ).stream().map( Map.Entry::getKey ).collect( Collectors.toList() );

        System.out.println( usersWithApple ); // [Joe, Denis]
        System.out.println( usersWithLaptop ); // [Joe]
    }
}
```

Maybe hazelcast has more convenient way to search in map values collections but I did not found it in the docs

Comment: @laur, In your example, It will be prettier to have a separate extractor for each field instead of 'if' clause in one extractor

Comment: @MikhailBaksheev ,What if my object in the list is just String instead of "Parameter " ?  How do I implement a ValueExtractor for that?

Comment: @MikhailBaksheev I am tring to store list of strings in the map.So key is a string and value is a list of string.How do I query this?

Comment: @selman I guess you need to find entries with specific value in a list, I'v added example in my answer above, sorry for the late answer